# rvestを用いたスクレイピング

Tags: r, web-scraping

R言語のrvestパッケージを利用して気象庁のページhttp://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/daily_s1.php?prec_no=44&block_no=47662&year=2016&month=7&day=&view=
からデータをデータフレームに収納したいと考えております。
ですが、カラムの構造が複雑になっているからかうまく行きません。
自分のソースコードは以下のとおりです。
詳しい方教えて下さい。もし全部のデータを取るのが難しければ平均気温だけで構いません。よろしくお願い致します。

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/daily_s1.php?prec_no=44&block_no=47662&year=2016&month=7&day=&view=")
table <- html_table(html)
```

このコードを実行すると最後の行に以下のエラーが出ます。

> table <- html_table(html)
>       Error: Table has inconsistent number of columns. Do you want fill = TRUE?

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、`table <- html_table(html, fill=T)` とすればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 無事作動しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくそのページにある最大なテーブルがほしいです。

問題は、そのテーブルのヘッダーがややこしいです。例えば、3行にある`最大`が二つのカラムを挟んでいます。

でもそれに当たる下のHTMLにただ一つのセルがコードしてあります。

したがって`html_table`に`fill = TRUE`を与えなければなりません。すると、でてくる`data.frame`に、満々じゃない行に適当に`NA`をいれてあげます。

```
URL <-
  paste0("http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/",
         "daily_s1.php?prec_no=44&block_no=47662&year=2016",
         "&month=7&day=&view=")
DF <- read_html(URL) %>% 
  html_node(xpath='//*[@id="tablefix1"]') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
head(DF)
#      日 気圧(hPa)     NA 降水量(mm)   NA   NA 気温(℃)   NA   NA 湿度(％)
# 1  現地      海面   <NA>       <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>
# 2  平均      平均   合計       最大 <NA> 平均    最高 最低 平均     最小
# 3 1時間    10分間   風速       風向 風速 風向    合計   値 <NA>     <NA>
# 4     1    1010.2 1013.0         --   --   --    25.6 30.6 22.0       83
# 5     2    1007.6 1010.4        0.0  0.0  0.0    27.0 31.8 23.4       79
# 6     3    1003.8 1006.6         --   --   --    29.2 35.4 24.6       71
#         NA 風向・風速(m/s)  NA           NA   NA     NA 日照時間(h)
# 1     <NA>            <NA>  NA         <NA>   NA   <NA>        <NA>
# 2 平均風速        最大風速  NA 最大瞬間風速   NA   降雪    最深積雪
# 3     <NA>            <NA>  NA         <NA>   NA   <NA>        <NA>
# 4       59             2.3 7.0       南南東 10.9 南南東         4.4
# 5       61             3.0 5.9           南  9.8 南南西         6.9
# 6       50             3.3 7.2       南南西 13.2   南西         7.6
#            雪(cm)                  NA   天気概況         NA
# 1            <NA>                <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 2 昼(06:00-18:00) 夜(18:00-翌日06:00)       <NA>       <NA>
# 3            <NA>                <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 4              --                  --   曇一時晴         曇
# 5              --                  -- 曇後時々晴 薄曇時々晴
# 6              --                  --   曇一時晴 晴後一時曇
```

ちゃんと見えるように、第1ー３行（とカラムのネーム）が出鱈目になってます。

その行を除いて、自分が与えたいネームをつけようとすすめます：

```
DF <- DF[-1L:-3L, ]
names(DF) <- my_names
```